# Bash repeating first line

Tags: bash

I just edited my .bash_profile to add git branch display. I based it on a version I found online, but now when I write something in the shell, at the end of the line, it overwrites the first line, then it starts wrapping to the new line.

```
function proml {
  case $TERM in
    xterm*)
     TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]'
    ;;
    *)
    TITLEBAR=""
    ;;
  esac

PS1="${TITLEBAR}\
\w$WHITE\$(parse_git_branch)\\e[m$ "
```

and this is the parse_git_branch function

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/[\1]/'
}
```

Since I don't know much about bash_profile I don't know where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem? A missing brace at the end of `proml` function>?

```
function proml {
  case $TERM in
    xterm*)
     TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]'
    ;;
    *)
    TITLEBAR=""
    ;;
  esac

PS1="${TITLEBAR}\
\w$WHITE\$(parse_git_branch)\\e[m$ "
}
```

Comment: I do have the curly brace at the end, I just didn't include it because there are a couple more lines before the function is done

Answer (score 0):

Assumeing `$WHITE` contains control codes to set the text color, you need to enclose it in
 `\[ ... \]` to prevent `bash` from thinking those characters contribute to the length of the prompt.

```
function proml {
  case $TERM in
    xterm*)
     TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]'
    ;;
    *)
    TITLEBAR=""
    ;;
  esac
}

PS1="${TITLEBAR}\
\w\[$WHITE\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[m\]$ "
```

Comment: I think I went overboard escaping some of the backslashes. Try this update (I actually tried this; it seems to work)

Comment: unfortunately, it still does the same thing

Comment: I missed one backslash when I edited; it might work now, but I'm less hopeful than before.

Comment: yeah still nothing. I am wondering if the problem is at parse_git_branch